# Cannot convert value of type 'Notifications.Type' to expected argument type 'Notifications'

Tags: swift

I trying to integreat firebase with my program to make true or false but I keep get the error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Notifications.Type' to expected argument type 'Notifications'

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileHost: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    @State private var draftProfile = Profile.default
      @State private var notifications = Notifications(id: "", prefersNotifications: true)

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            HStack {
                if editMode?.wrappedValue == .active {
                    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                        draftProfile = modelData.profile
                        notifications = modelData.notifications
                        editMode?.animation().wrappedValue = .inactive
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                EditButton()
            }

            if editMode?.wrappedValue == .inactive {
                ProfileSummary(profile: modelData.profile, notifications: modelData.notifications)
            } else {
                ProfileEditor(profile: $draftProfile, notifications: $notifications)
                    .onAppear {
                        draftProfile = modelData.profile
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        modelData.profile = draftProfile
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ProfileHost_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileHost()
            .environmentObject(ModelData())
    }
}
```

Modeldata is the file I made the notifications var

This the code of modeldata

```
import Foundation
import Combine

final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var landmarks: [Landmark] = load("landmarkData.json")
    var hikes: [Hike] = load("hikeData.json")
    @Published var profile = Profile.default
    @Published  var notifications = Notifications.self


    var features: [Landmark] {
        landmarks.filter { $0.isFeatured }
    }

    var categories: [String: [Landmark]] {
        Dictionary(
            grouping: landmarks,
            by: { $0.category.rawValue }
        )
    }
}

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

at

```
if editMode?.wrappedValue == .inactive {
                ProfileSummary(profile: modelData.profile, notifications: modelData.notifications)
```

I get an error that says.

> Cannot convert value of type 'Notifications.Type' to expected argument
> type 'Notifications'

I tried to look at other wedsites like [github](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/ixqp3m/swiftui_error_cannot_convert_value_of_type/) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/ixqp3m/swiftui_error_cannot_convert_value_of_type/)

Comment: It's likely `var notifications = Notifications()`

Comment: Please add the definition of `ModelData` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
@Published  var notifications = Notifications.self //<--type not value
```

Should be something like

```
@Published  var notifications : Notifications = Notifications(id: "", prefersNotifications: true)
```